# Mysql databases not recogniced after moving files

Tags: mysql, innodb, percona

I have a problem with my database/schema.

I wanted to change the raid configuration on my server. To do so, I first shutdown the mysql server, which is actually percona5.6, and then moved all the files to another location.

I then restarted the server and configured the raid.
Then I let it boot, unfortunately the mysql server started as well and of course couldn't find the moved databases.

When I then moved the files back to the reconfigured drive and started the server, the databases where gone.

All databases have the right owner and group (percona:percona) and are innodb tables (file_per_table=1).

My question now is, how can I reinitialize the databases, if possible?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: 1. check the error log 2. probably not the correct forum for this question

Comment: you are right @ethrbunny. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not have to reinitialise the databases if they are in the correct directories and if **all** directories have the correct permissions for the database user. Also check if the directories have the correct owner.

Comment: I just forgot to change the owner of the main directory on the new raid... thanks so much mark